# CSS popup Login form and PHP Login Script

Tags: php, html, css

I have a CSS popup which brings up a login form.  When I try to log in it just reloads the page and the popup appears again.

Here is the link to open the popup

```
<a href="#login_form" class="btn signInBtn">Sign In</a>
```

Here is the HTML for my popup login form.

```
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="login_form"></a>    
    <div class="popup">
        <h2 class="modal-header">Sign In</h2>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="signIn-form">
                <div class="errorMessage alert alert-error" id="errorMsg">
                    <h4>Whoops</h4>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $errorMsg; ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <fieldset class="l-formMain">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label class="applyForm-label" for="email">Email</label>
                            <input class="applyForm-input required" type="email" id="login_email" placeholder="name@example.com" tabindex="1" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label class="applyForm-label" for="password">Password</label>
                            <input class="applyForm-input required" type="password" id="login_password" tabindex="2" />
                            <span class="forgotPassLi">
                                <a href="#forgotpass" class="v-secondary" style="position:relative; left:-150px;">Forgot your Password?</a>
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="modal-buttonHolder">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-large" id="login" value="Sign In" tabindex="3" />
                </div>                    
            </form>
        </div> 
        <a href="#close" class="modal-closeBtn">×</a>       
    </div>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $login_email = $_POST['login_email'];
    $login_password = $_POST['login_password'];

    // error handling conditional checks go here
    if ((!$login_email) || (!$login_password)) { 
    $errorMsg = 'Please fill in both fields';
    } else { // Error handling is complete so process the info if no errors
    include 'scripts/connect_to_mysql.php'; // Connect to the database
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($login_email); // After we connect, we secure the string before adding to query       
    $pass = md5($login_password); // Add MD5 Hash to the password variable they supplied after filtering it     
    // Make the SQL query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' AND email_activated='1'";
           $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    if($result){
        $login_check = mysql_num_rows($result);
    }   
    // If login check number is greater than 0 (meaning they do exist and are activated)
    if($login_check > 0){ 
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                $id = $row["ID"];
                $_SESSION['ID'] = $id;
                // Create the idx session var
                $_SESSION['idx'] = base64_encode("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$id");
                // Create session var for their username
                $email = $row["email"];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['userId'] = $row["ID"];

                mysql_query("UPDATE members SET last_log_date=now() WHERE ID='$id' LIMIT 1");

            } // close while
            // All good they are logged in, send them to homepage then exit script
            if (isset($_SESSION["email"]) || count($_SESSION["email"]) > 0) {  
                header("Location: http://localhost/dashboard.php");
            }               
    } else { // Run this code if login_check is equal to 0 meaning they do not exist
        $errorMsg = "Either the email or password (or both) are incorrect. Make sure that you've typed them correctly and try again";
    }
    }// Close else after error checks
    }
?>
```

Comment: try setting the action of your form to the page without the #login_form in the url (I'm guessing this show's when you submit the form)

Comment: Although you could just use $_REQUEST instead of $_POST and you really should consider using prepared statements or at least a mysql_escape_string($email) and the same with the $password to avoid sql injections

Comment: @ITroubs You're right, it's not a good example regards to security.  I've edited the script to cater for that now.

Comment: @TommyBs Hi Tommy, the #login_form is what triggers the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is not posting to anywhere. So by default it goes to the current page.

Try  adding an action and method attribute to the form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://url.of.PHP.page/containing/login/code">
```

Comment: Hi Husman, I've added the post and the action to go to the dashboard.  The page goes straight through to the URL but it seems like it's not going through the PHP code.

Comment: Thats because your PHP code is looking for: if(isset($_POST['login'])) and your submit button has no name attribute, just the id set to 'login'. To remedy this, add name='login' to the submit button.